# Восклицательный знак в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Задание в проверочной работе 2 класса. Даны предложения, нужно проставить знаки препинания.
— Привет, Саша Рад тебя видеть
— И я рад

Ребенок проставил:
— Привет, Саша Рад тебя видеть.
— И я рад.

Учитель исправил на:
— Привет, Саша. Рад тебя видеть!
— И я рад!

И снизил оценку. Согласна, что ребенок забыл точку после «Саша», это снижает оценку на полбалла. Поясните, пожалуйста: разве не может быть варианта, что в зависимости от настроения может ставиться или запятая, или восклицательный знак?

Предложения не зачитывались вслух. Дети решали на листках, читая про себя.

Answer (score 1):

По смыслу получается так, что если человек действительно рад, то именно восклицательный знак выражает интонацию радости, восторга.

Если не поставить восклицательный знак, то так можно выразить лицемерие (на самом деле не рад, а притворяется) или ложь (*И я рад.* — просто чтобы не обидеть человека). Ещё такая интонация может быть, если у человека депрессия и нет никакой радости, но хочется сказать другому приятные слова. Но тогда это тоже ложь.

Так что в "естественном" контексте (если эмоция радости не обман) правильно поставить восклицательный знак.